# Eliminate duplicate key with same value from associative array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Zimbabwe
    [country] => Zimbabwe
    [1] => 2
    [counts] => 2
)
Array
(
    [0] => Tunisia
    [country] => Tunisia
    [1] => 6
    [counts] => 6
)   
I want output like below:  
Array
(
    [country] => Zimbabwe 
    [counts] => 2
)  
Array
(
    [country] => Tunisia   
    [counts] => 6
)
```

Comment: [array_unique()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

Comment: When you retrieve the data from your database (you're probably using a `mysql_fetch_array()` or `mysqli_fetch_array()` call aren't you), tell the fetch to return an associative array, not both

Comment: am using while($rowCountry = mssql_fetch_array($resultCountryCount)){ print_r($rowCountry);}  .thanks for your help

Comment: @MarkBaker 's suggestion is much better than mine if you are using `mysql_fetch_array`. ;)

Comment: @MarkBaker is correct 100%. great eyes.

Answer (score 2):

Try fetching this from your database using

```
while($rowCountry = mssql_fetch_array($resultCountryCount), MSSQL_ASSOC){
    print_r($rowCountry);
}
```

or

```
while($rowCountry = mssql_fetch_assoc($resultCountryCount)){
    print_r($rowCountry);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be better to go with `@mark` otherwise you may try this too

```
  $a = Array
    (
        0 => 'Zimbabwe',
        'country' => 'Zimbabwe',
        1=> 2,
        'counts' => 2,
    );

    function myfun($array){
        $check= array();
        foreach($array as $k => $v){
            if(in_array($v,$check)){
                unset($array[$k]);
            }   
            array_push($check, $v);
        }
        return $array;
    }
    $a = myfun($a);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($a);
```